# Create BGR Mat from three single Mats in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have three Mats, that are all the same size, the same datatype etc. Each one represents a channel and now I want to merge them together as one RGB-(BGR)-Image.

The data itself comes from another computation, so the code looks like the following at the moment:

```
Mat blue = Mat(Size(1920,1080),CV_8UC1,blue_result);
Mat red = Mat(Size(1920,1080),CV_8UC1,red_result);
Mat green = Mat(Size(1920,1080),CV_8UC1,green_result);
```

Is there an easy way to merge these three matrices as one `CV_8UC3` Mat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [merge()](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7d7b4d6c6ee504b30a20b1680029c7b4) function to do it.

```
Mat blue = Mat(Size(1920,1080),CV_8UC1,blue_result);
Mat red = Mat(Size(1920,1080),CV_8UC1,red_result);
Mat green = Mat(Size(1920,1080),CV_8UC1,green_result);     

Mat planes[] = { blue, green, red };
Mat bgrImage;
merge(planes, 3, bgrImage);
```